# Python semantics - Multiple parameters in declaration of for loop

Tags: python

Sorry to ask a dumb question, but could somebody tell me what the following means

```
for ctype, (codename, name) in searched_perms:
```

I don't understand what's going on the parenthesis. `for ctype in serached_perms:` would make sense.

I realise that the answer is in the python docs somewhere but since I don't know what I'm looking for, it's difficult to find the explaination.

Comment: [Tuple unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctype, (codename, name)` is the same thing as `(ctype, (codename, name))`. Therefore, `searched_perms` needs to be a sequence of things of the form (a,(b,c)), and on each loop iteration the variables `ctype`, `codename`, `name` will be set to a,b,c.

Answer (score 6):

This is practically equivalent to

```
for x in search_perms:
     ctype, y = x
     codename, name = y
```

or

```
for x in search_perms:
    ctype = x[0]
    codename = x[1][0]
    name = x[1][1]
```

i.e., it unpacks the items from `search_perms` as pairs, then unpacks the second item of each pair as a pair as well.

Example:

```
>>> d = {"ham": "yes", "spam": "no", "eggs": "please"}
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     print("%s? %s" % (k, v))
...     
eggs? please
ham? yes
spam? no
>>> for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
...     print("question %d: %s? %s" % (i, k, v))
...     
question 0: eggs? please
question 1: ham? yes
question 2: spam? no
```

This works because `enumerate(d.iteritems())` generates pairs where each second element is again a pair:

```
>>> list(enumerate(d.iteritems()))
[(0, ('eggs', 'please')), (1, ('ham', 'yes')), (2, ('spam', 'no'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list `searchedparams` should looks something like this:

```
In [1]: L = []

In [2]: L.append(('a', ('b', 'c')))

In [3]: L.append(('d', ('e', 'f')))

In [4]: L
Out[4]: [('a', ('b', 'c')), ('d', ('e', 'f'))]

In [6]: for ctype, (codename, name) in L:
    print ctype, codename, name
   ...: 
a b c
d e f
```

`('a', ('b', 'c'))` is a tuple of 2 values, where the right value is also a tuple of two values.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `searched_perms` is an iterable that returns two elements during iteration: the first one is `ctype` and the second is a tuple, composed of another two elements: `(codename, name)`. So `searched_perms` looks something like this:

```
[[ctype1, (code1, name1)], [ctype2, (code2, name2)], ...]
```

The syntax `for ctype, (codename, name) in searched_perms` allows the extraction of all the contents in `searched_perms`, element by element.