# python function returning an list

Tags: python, django

I have a python function that returns

```
def edit_user(request):
    error  = False
    errMsg = ""

    id = int(request.POST.get("add_user"))
    if config.editUser(id) != True
        error = True
        errMsg =  _('Failed to edit existing user.')

    return [error, errMsg]
```

I'm calling this function from another python function.

How do I get these two return values, (`error` and `errMsg`) into two separate variables?

Answer (score 2):

Like this: `error, errMsg = edit_user(request)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the results to a `list` or `tuple`:

```
error,errMsg = edit_user(...)
(error,errMsg) = edit_user(...)
[error,errMsg] = edit_user(...)
```

The first syntax is the most preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Hui Zheng is right - `error, errMsg = edit_user(request)` will do it.

The process is called unpacking and can be used to unpack complicated data structures (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950176/python-semantics-multiple-parameters-in-declaration-of-for-loop) for another example, and have a look at the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) for more info).

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers: there's no reason to make a list here at all. Just do this:

```
return error, errMsg
```